# How to fix redirection to the login page (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I make the /welcome page available to everyone, but when I go to it, I am still redirected to the login page

WebSecurityConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig{
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder){
        UserDetails admin = User.builder().username("admin").password(encoder.encode("admin")).build();
        UserDetails user = User.builder().username("user").password(encoder.encode("user")).build(); 
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();

    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

siteController:

```java
@Controller

public class siteController {
    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome(){
        return "welcome.html";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String admin(){
        return "admin.html";
    }
}
```

DemoApplication:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I tried to make all the pages available without authorization and I managed to log in to them without authorization, it looked like this

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
 
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
         return http.build();
```

But when I write like this

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();

    }
```

I am no longer allowed on all pages without authorization

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you try also set permitAll to `welcome.html` path ? I mean `resources/.../welcome.html`

Comment: I just tried it, it still redirects to the authorization page

Comment: @minby Show your Spring Security `DEBUG` logs. It will show the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thank you all for your help, I've sorted out this problem.
I deleted the siteController file and replaced it with the MvsConfig configuration file, in which I indicated how I understand creating new controllers and naming them, in the end I got this:

instead of the siteController file:

```java
@Controller

public class siteController {
    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome(){
        return "welcome.html";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String admin(){
        return "admin.html";
    }
}
```

I made a file MvcConfig:

```java
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/welcome").setViewName("welcome");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("welcome");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/admin").setViewName("admin");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

and my WebSecurityConfig file configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/welcome").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) guide and it allowed public access to `/welcome` route and redirected to login page for other routes. Your code is also looking fine. Check again your code against that guide.

Below is the code that worked for me.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/","/welcome").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll());
                //.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle dependencies :

```xml
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    //  Temporary explicit version to fix Thymeleaf bug
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6:3.1.1.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: I used the same dependencies and the same configuration as you recommended, but now I have an error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: i don't have an error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS if i change 
```java
.formLogin((form) -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll());
```
to
```java
 .formLogin(withDefaults())
```
but i stiil redirects

Comment: @minby Can you share your minimal code to reproduce same issue in github repo if possible?

Answer (score 0):

I did some test some testing when I changed `@Controller` to `@RestController` everything starts to work fine as expected, but that not a solution for your issue, so I did another thing instead of whitelisting what should allowed without auth inside `authorizeHttpRequests` I added `securityMatcher`

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .securityMatcher("/admin", "/admin/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        return http.build();

    }
```

With this `@Controller` works perfectly fine. I guess maybe there is some bug related to using `@Controller` and `WebSecurityConfig`